# Virtual hosts on mamp pro, domain with and without www

Tags: mamp

In Mamp pro I want both the www.test.com and test.com domains to be redirected to the same folder on localhost, do I have to enter them both or is there some option to automatically apply the settings of one to the other so i don't have to enter them both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `ServerAlias` in the virtual host config. For MAMP PRO you should be abale to just add `ServerAlias test.com` to the `Customized virtual host general settings` box on the `Advanced Virtual Hosts Configuration` tab.

Otherwise, locate the virtual host declaration in `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache` and add it manually.

```
<VirtualHost *>
  DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.com/
  ServerName www.test.com
  ServerAlias test.com
  <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.com/">
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You will need to restart Apache to make the configuration active.

[Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias)

Comment: where do I insert that in Mamp pro?

Comment: See updated answer, you should be able to so this the Advanced Virtual Hosts Configuration tab without touching the config files.